# Why isn't freetype loading these functions?

Tags: c++, freetype

I have freetype as a dll. All of the header files are auto-completing on visual studio and the following statements compile fine: `FT_Library ft; FT_Face face;`. However, it can't find `FT_Init_Freetype` or `FT_New_Face` (`LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ...`). Here's my full code:

````
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <freetype/freetype.h>
#include <freetype/ftcache.h>
#include <freetype/ftbitmap.h>
// Just getting desperate including headers here

void initFreetype() {
    FT_Library ft;

    FT_Face face;
    
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not init freetype library\n");
        return;
    }
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "C:\\Font\\verdana.ttf", 0, &face)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open font\n");
        return;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Did you link to the library?

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings Yes, the .dll is in the project folder and everything before the if statements works. Also, the headers are auto-completing meaning that visual studio can find the header files.

Comment: But did you link to the library? You have to do that during the build. Otherwise the program won't know that there _is_ a DLL to find at runtime! Which FreeType documentation are you using at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

I was stupid and was pointing to freetype\objs instead of freetype\objs\Win32\Debug in the linker.

I'm still getting other errors (`unresolved external symbol _sprintf...` from freetype.lib(bdf.obj) though, so I think something else may be wrong too.

Edit: That last error was fixed here: https://community.cypress.com/thread/14289?start=0&tstart=0 by linking legacy_stdio_definitions.lib